# loading state never get true??(React - Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am creating an app that get the user data from the backend when the user login and display it in the user profile, i need to set loading statement like  `loading...` in place of the profile before all data comes from the backend then display the data instead

my action creators:

```
export const loginUser = (loginData) => (dispatch) => {

    axios.post('/signin', loginData)
        .then(res => {
            let FBIdToken = `Bearer ${token}`;
            localStorage.setItem('FBIdToken', FBIdToken);
            dispatch(getUserData());
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response && err.response.data
            });
        });
}

export const getUserData = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: LOADING_USER });

    axios.get('/user')
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_USER,
                payload: res.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

reducer:

```
const intialState = {
    authenticated: false,
    loading: false,
    credentials: {},
};

export default (state = intialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_USER:
            return {
                authenticated: true,
                loading: false,
                ...action.payload,
            }
            case LOADING_USER:
                return {
                    loading: true,
                    ...state
                }

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

login page:

```
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {  
        e.preventDefault();
        loginUser(loginData);
    }
```

now when i click the submit button on login page `handlesubmit` function run the `loginUser` action creator that in role run the `getUserData` action creator.

now in getUserData action creator this action get dispatched `{type: LOADING_USER}` and this state should be returned from the reducer before the userData come from the backend:

```
{
  loading: true,
  credentials: {},
  authenticated: false
}
```

and then the data comes after axios request and change `loading` to `false` and set the user credentials, but this not is not the scenario in my case, as loading never get true in my code and `loading...` never get displayed before the user credentials set as a user profile..**what is the wrong in my code?**

Comment: instead of `loading: true, ...state`, try `...state, loading: true`?

Comment: what??..this works..please tell me why that happened, is properties order matter in objects???

Comment: @tammay can you plz, add an answer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment above, you need to switch the order of `loading: true` and `...state`.

Reason: (as you guessed it) the order matters when you are spreading an object, especially if the object being spread also contains the `loading` key inside it. So if you keep `...state` after the `loading: true`, it overrides the `loading: true` with whatever value `state` has for `loading`. And I guess that's not something we would want. Hence, keep the `...state` before `loading: true` to get the expected result.

Comment: one of the best and shocking answers i got on stackoverflow : ), Thanks, this really helps and saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

you are spreading the previous state after your current updated state :

```
case LOADING_USER:
  return {
    loading: true,
    ...state
  }
```

you need to do reverse:

```
case LOADING_USER:
   return {
     ...state,
     loading: true,              
   }
```

by spreading the state after your loading, your previous state got overrides the new state, but by spreading the previous state first, you overriding only the loading part of your state!

Comment: That was new to me, i thought redux take over that and so the new values always added and the old one skipped, thank you

Comment: for that kind of control over your store you can use something called Immer! which will give you an draft of your state and you can change it by the key of your state!

Comment: thanks for that info, redux is hard to wrap your mind around,